# Setting up a PCIe serial card that doesn't appear to possess I/O ports

Tags: serial-port, pci

I am trying to assign a Brainboxes PX-246 PCI express serial card to a /dev/ttyS.. device using the `setserial` command, however this card does not seem to possess an I/O port address (only memory addresses).

`lspci -v` gives the following:

```
05:00.0 Serial controller: Brain Boxes Device 4016 (rev 02) (prog-if 06 [16950])
        Subsystem: Brain Boxes Device 4016
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
        Memory at f7600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at f7400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
        Memory at f7200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
        Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 00-30-e0-11-11-00-01-50
        Capabilities: [110] Power Budgeting <?>
```

Is it possible to assign a memory address to a serial device instead of an I/O port?

At the moment I am testing the card under Ubuntu 16.04, but it will eventually be used on a Fedora system.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Very likely it uses a different chipset with memory mapped registers (first 16K space). The [datasheet of the card](http://dl.staticbb.com/files/catalog/product/PX/PX-246/documents/PX-246-datasheet.pdf) doesn't say which one, so look at your card, read what's written on the big black chip, google for a datasheet, and see if you can find a matching driver for it. I'ts entirely possible there's no pre-written driver for Linux.

Comment: The chip is an OXPCIe952. As far as I can tell this chipset should already be supported by my kernel (4.4), but the serial card's vendor/device ID is not recognised; I can't see anything relating to this serial port in dmesg. So I may need to modify one of the linux source code files (this one maybe: 8250_pci.c?) and recompile the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet of the OXPCIe952 is e.g. [here](http://www.semiconductorstore.com/pdf/newsite/oxford/oxpcie952_ds.pdf), it says on page 3 that the chip can be enabled in several modes depending on the hardware strappings of 5 pins.

The UART is available in legacy mode (with I/O addresses) and native mode (memory mapped, with the 3 BARs shown in your question). If you don't have any other functions (PCI devices like `05:00.1`, `05:00.2` etc.), this means your card is enabled for one native UART, 5th line in the chart on page 3. It also explains what the BARs are used for (if you are interested) on page 13. As I guessed, the first BAR is memory mapped I/O for the UART.

The file `8250_pci.c` indeed does contain PCI ids both for legacy and native UARTs with this chip, so yes, first thing I'd try is to add your PCI ids to this file, recompile, and see if it works.

Comment: Updating `8250_pci.c` with the Brainboxes vendor ID worked perfectly, thanks very much!

Comment: Don't forget to submit this to the kernel developers so it gets included in the next kernel. I guess for such a small change, a bugreport would do.